# insert in for each with async await

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

**error on query execution**

```
var records = [{name:'John',age:24},{name:'Sarah',age:28},{name:'Linda',age:23}];

connection.getSession().then(session => {
   async function insertRecords() {
      await Promise.all(records.map(async function (element) {
         let util = {};
         util['name'] = element['name'];
         util['age'] = element['age'] || null;                   
         let query = `INSERT INTO users SET
           name =?,
           age=?
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            name=VALUES(name),
            age=VALUES(age)`;

        session.sql(query).bind([util.name, util.age]).execute()
           .then(() => {})
           .catch((error) => {
              console.error('cannot execute the query');
              console.error('error', error);
           });
      }))
   }

   insertRecords()
      .then(data => console.log('data', data))
      .catch(err => console.log('err', err))

}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    session.close();
});
```

I am getting the following error on execution.

{ severity: 0,
     code: 5015,
     sqlState: 'HY000',
     msg: 'Too many arguments' } }

Comment: That is an error with your query, not with `async/await`, right?

Comment: The query seems to be working fine if I execute it in workbench

Comment: I've never seen VALUES( syntax after the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command.  I couldn't tell you why that works in workbench but not in node, but try remove it anyway.

Comment: The query looks fine. There are however some issues with async handling as pointed out by the existing answer. What version of the driver are you using? I'm not able to reproduce this behavior.

Using your code snippet as is (with an existing table with a valid schema) just returns `data undefined`. Which makes sense given the async handling issues.

Disclaimer: I'm the MySQL Node.js X DevAPI driver lead dev.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Promise.all`, you `map` on `records` but your resolver function doesn't return anything. You would need to return a promise. To do so, you should just replace your `session.sql` block with the following: `return session.sql(query).bind([util.name, util.age]).execute()`.

That would return an array of Promises to `Promise.all`, and it would work. The error handling is already done when you call your `insertRecords` function so you don't need to worry about it in your resolver.

Comment: I am getting the same error after making the changes